# Why do my command line programs launch chrome canary instead of normal chrome (mac)?

Tags: node.js, macos, browser, command-line

I recently installed Chrome Canary for testing purposes. Before this, starting local server from the command line with storybook (and similar tools) would launch normal chrome. Now those tools launch Chrome Canary.

I have checked system settings and normal Chrome is my default browser. Also, oddly, if I run:

```
open http://www.example.com
```

this will launch normal Chrome.

How can I check what browser those tools are looking for when they attempt to launch a browser? I'm on MacOS with Ventura 13.4.1.